# Просмотр истории транзакций Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть  Sql Server 2005 и Sql Management Studio 2005 нужно просмотреть **историю транзакций с запросами**. Так вот, как её просмотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы посмотреть историю транзакций можно использовать SQL Profiler, с помощью него можно просмотреть все транзакции и запросы которые приходили с момента запуска SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

[Log analysis and undo for SQL Server](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/)
Не пользовался.

Answer (score 0):

по большому счету - никак. Особенно с транзакциями. При изменении данных все операции пишутся в лог и его вроде как можно посмотреть сторонними утилитами, но я не уверен, что там содержатся уровни изоляции транзакций. Для селектов никакой истории вообще не ведется, насколько я знаю.